# Как взять сертификат из хранилища в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows-service

У нас есть сервис для отправки данных он берет сертификат из хранилище. Я пробую взять из хранилище нужный мне сертификат но количество сертифкатов раняется к нулю. Сертификат установлен. Что бы понять свою ошибку я создал тестовый desktop приложения и запустил свой код и оно работает нормально. но на сервис приложении оно всё еще не работает. Вот исходный код который ищет сертификат.

```
function GetCertificate2(thumbPrint:WideString) : ICertificate2;
var
  Store: TStore;
  certificates: ICertificates;
  certificate2: ICertificate2;
  ThumbPrintFromStore: WideString;
  i : Integer;
begin
  thumbPrint := StringReplace(thumbPrint, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

  //Создаем объект хранилища
  Store := TStore.Create(nil);

  //Открываем хранилище сертификатов для пользователя (Папка Личные)
  Store.Open(CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE, 'My', CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_READ_ONLY);

  //Получаем коллекцию сертификатов
  certificates := Store.Certificates;

  //Находим нужный сертификат по отпечатку
  for i := 1 to certificates.count do
  begin
    certificate2 := IInterface(certificates.Item[i]) as ICertificate2;
    ThumbPrintFromStore := certificate2.Thumbprint;

    if UpperCase(ThumbPrintFromStore) = UpperCase(thumbPrint) then
    begin
      Result := certificate2;
      break;
    end;
  end;

  //Закрываем хранилище
  Store.close();
end;
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно итерируете от 1 до Count `for i := 1 to certificates.count do .. certificates.Item[i]`, а не от 0 до Count-1 ?

Comment: всеё равно количество ровняется к нулю

Comment: Я же выще написал что с этим кодос на просто приложении всё раюотает отлично а на сервисе не может найти не одного сертификата

Comment: Ну так вы же указываете CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE. Хранилище текущего пользователя. А сервис по умолчанию работает под пользователем LocalSystem.